# node.js fs.readFile how to tell when reached EOF

Tags: node.js

I am just trying out node.js and the fs package.

With async IO in fs.readFile(), how does the callback handler know if the reader has hit EOF or it merely exhausted the read buffer size, was swapped out, or any other condition? There is also no file handle visible to interrogate. Is that a wrong node idiom?

Thanks a lot.
Dinesh

--

@Abe. So I changed the code to assume I will get the whole thing in one go, but hit error with a large file. But in all other cases it ran just perfectly

```
"buffer.js:194
      this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
                    ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:194:21)
    at fs.js:225:16
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)"
```

Comment: I suspect that if anything other than EOF has occurred, then the `err` parameter in the callback will have something in it.  Have you encountered a situation where something besides EOF has occurred and there is nothing in `err`?

Comment: @Abe, thanks for the hint. As I said earlier, I am just learning node and want understand this beast before using it, so that I don't have to discover an issue at 3AM some Saturday night. I did modify the code to assume I get the whole thing in one go and hit an error in one test case (updated q)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fs.readFile()` buffers the entire contents of the file (it reads until EOF). If there was an error reading the file, the `err` parameter is set. Otherwise you get the contents of your file as the second argument to your callback.

Comment: I wish node documentation was less muddy. Python is so much better at it.